# What are the benefits to convert text to date in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I want to store some dates into a table, why should I use date function to pass dates instead of inserting dates , simply, as text format.

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
Birthday Date    /* date standart format YYYY-MM-DD */
);

INSERT INTO dates (Birthday) 
VALUES (date('2005-12-30'));
```

Instead of

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
Birthday text     
);

INSERT INTO dates (Birthday) 
VALUES ('2005-12-30');
```

Comment: You can just use the string.  Why are you asking the question?

Comment: I have learned in PLSQL to insert a date I should use TO_DATE. I'm trying to understand what is the purpose of the function when you can just use a string.

Comment: Oracle has a very arcane default date format.  In Oracle, you should use `DATE '2005-12-30'`.  In fact, `DATE` is ANSI standard, so it should be used in all databases that support it -- but a string with YYYY-MM-DD is commonly used and has been supported by lots of databases for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no DATE [data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Declaring a column as DATE happens to use numeric [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), but that does not matter when you store date strings in such a column.

SQLite's [date() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) can convert other date formats into a `yyyy-mm-dd` string, and apply modifiers.
If the input already is a string in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, and if you are not using any modifiers, then the result of the function is guaranteed to be the same as the input, and the function call is pointless.

Answer (score -2):

It is completely doable by storing it in a text format. But you will then be restricted to ordering and filtering the column as a text instead of a date. Meaning, if you need to order or filter the data by date I strongly recommend you to use one of the date/time formats. Also DBMS can optimize the queries, knowing it is a date...